# A state mutation was detected between dispatches but I haven't mutated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I know this question has been asked before, but in almost all of them talk about the OP mutating the state directly, which I've tried to avoid using techniques like the spread operator (in both objects and arrays) but in spite of that I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path `courses.0`. This may cause incorrect behavior. (http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)
  at invariant (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:922), <anonymous>:40:15)
  at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:3825), <anonymous>:50:36)
  at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:3846), <anonymous>:14:16)
  at dispatch (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:3853), <anonymous>:37:18)
  at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:1151), <anonymous>:63:5)
  at eval (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:3846), <anonymous>:11:18)
  at Object.eval [as saveCourse] (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:3860), <anonymous>:4:12)
  at Object.ManageCoursePage._this.saveCourse [as onSave] (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:2080), <anonymous>:134:27)
  at CourseForm._this.onHandleSave (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:2052), <anonymous>:93:19)
  at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:1301), <anonymous>:69:16)
```

I read [the article that the error points to](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments), and as it suggests I checked if I was manually mutating the state in my reducer and I can't see where that could be happening:

```
const courseReducer = (state = initialState.courses, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_COURSE_SUCCESS:
      return action.courses;
    case types.CREATE_COURSE_SUCCESS:
    //This action throw the error 
      debugger;      
      return [
        ...state,
        Object.assign({}, action.course)
      ];
    case types.UPDATE_COURSE_SUCCESS:
     //This action throw the error
      debugger;
      return [
        ...state.filter(course => course.id !== action.course.id),
        Object.assign({}, action.course)
      ];
    case types.DELETE_COURSE_SUCCESS:
      return [...state.filter(course => course.id !== action.courseId)];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here's [a sandbox with part of the application](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zmY3z39p7) that can be used to replicate the error, which weirdly only happens from times to times when I create a new course or try to edit an existing one (actions `CREATE_COURSE_SUCCESS` and `UPDATE_COURSE_SUCCESS`respectively in my `courseReducer`)

[image: Edit React-Redux(Question) - Challenges]

[image]

[image]

I'd really appreciate if anyone could help me figure out where could be lying the source of this error.

Comment: Can we see how you use your state, via `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: Sure! It is a bit messy, but I already added under an Edit. Btw you can found the same code in the sandbox I included in my question, just look for the file `components/course/ManageCoursePage.js`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are mutating state, inside `CoursesPage.js`, in `mapStateToProps`:

```
let courses = state.courses.sort((c1, c2) =>
  c1.title.localeCompare(c2.title, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }),
);
```

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example) is an **in place operation**, so it mutates the source array by sorting the source array in place. That means, `sort` is mutating `state.courses`, thus causing the error. Instead, make a copy of `state.courses` before you sort it:

```
[...state.courses]
```

The above uses [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to spread the elements into a new array essentially cloning it. This is the same as [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example). Then you can sort it like so:

```
let courses = [...state.courses].sort((c1, c2) =>
  c1.title.localeCompare(c2.title, 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }),
);
```

This will not mutate the original `state.courses` and will not throw an error.

---

Note: There are also some places where you are mutating `this.state` directly, such as in line 32 of `ManageCoursePage.js` where you do:

```
this.state.errors = {}
```

Only ever mutate the `this.state` object in the constructor of the component. Use `setState` instead.

Comment: My bad! Would you mind telling me how did you manage to find the places where I was manually mutating the state? There was no reference to the `CoursesPage.js`  in the error stack.

Comment: I suspected it had something to do with `mapStateToProps` due to the error message and I looked for it in there. The message says "between dispatches" so it had to do with `connect`ing or in the reducer. Since the reducer was fine I went to see your `connect`s. Also, doing a Ctrl+F search for `state = ` can help sometimes.

Comment: OK. I just thought that perhaps there was a package for that :)